# java.lang.NullPointerException exception is occurred when running the test script Page Object Model using Selenium Web Driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

```
package com.qa.base;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import com.qa.util.TestUitl;

public class TestBase {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static Properties prop;

    // Creating a Constructor
    public TestBase() {

        prop = new Properties();

        try {
            File file = new File("/APIAutomation/CRMTest/src/main/java/com/qa/config/config.properties");

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            prop.load(fis);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    
    public static void initializtion() {
        
        String browser = prop.getProperty("browser");
        
        if(browser.equals("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/APIAutomation/chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Quit Running Script");
        }
        
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TestUitl.PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TestUitl.IMPLICIT_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
        
        
    }
}

Page Factory
package com.qa.pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import com.qa.base.TestBase;

public class loginPage extends TestBase{
    
    //Page Factory
        @FindBy(name="email")
        WebElement email;
        
        @FindBy(name="password")
        WebElement password;
        
        @FindBy(xpath=".//div[@class='ui fluid large blue submit button']")
        WebElement loginButton;
        
        @FindBy(xpath="//div[@class ='column']/div[2][@class='ui message']")
        WebElement OldLogin;
        
        //Initialization the Page Object
        
        public loginPage() {
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        }
        
        //Actions
        
        public String validateLoginPageTitle() {
            return driver.getTitle();
            
        }
        
        public String validateUserName() {
            
            return OldLogin.getText();
            
            
        }
        
        public HomePage login(String user, String pass) {
            
            email.sendKeys(user);
            password.sendKeys(pass);
            loginButton.click();
            
            return new HomePage();
        }
    }



Page Factory HomePage
package com.qa.pages;


import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import com.qa.base.TestBase;

public class HomePage extends TestBase{
    
    //PageFactory
        @FindBy(xpath = ".//div[@id='main-nav']/a[@href='/home']")
        WebElement Homepage;
        
        @FindBy(xpath =".//div/span[@class='user-display']")
        WebElement username;
        
        @FindBy(xpath =".//span[contains(text(),'Contacts')]")
        WebElement contactlink;
        
        @FindBy(xpath="//a[5][contains(@href,'/deals')]")
        WebElement dealslink;
        
        //Initializing Page Object
        public HomePage() {
            
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
            
        }
        

        
        //Actions
        public String validateHomePage() {

        return driver.getTitle();
            
        }
        
        
        public boolean validateHomePageDisplayed() {
            return Homepage.isDisplayed();
        }
        
        public String validateUser() {
            
            return username.getText();
        }
        
        public boolean verifyUsername() {
            return username.isDisplayed();
        }
        
        
        
        public ContactPage clickContactLink() {         
            contactlink.click();
            return new ContactPage();
        }
        
        public DealsPage clickDeals() {
            dealslink.click();
            return new DealsPage();
        }
    }



Test Case Class
package com.crm.qa.TestCases;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.qa.base.TestBase;
import com.qa.pages.ContactPage;
import com.qa.pages.HomePage;
import com.qa.pages.loginPage;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;

public class HomePageTest extends TestBase {
    
    loginPage loginpage;
    HomePage homepage;
    ContactPage contactpage;
    
    //Create a constructor  of  HomePageTest and call the super class i.e the TestBase class constructor will be called
    public HomePageTest()  {
        
        super();
    }
    
    
    // test case should be separated - independent with each other
    // before each test cases - launch the browser and login
    // after each test cases - close the browser
    
    @BeforeMethod
    
    public void setUp() {
        
        initializtion();
        loginpage = new loginPage();
        //Login method is returning homepage object
        homepage = loginpage.login(prop.getProperty("username"), prop.getProperty("password"));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void verifyHomePageTitleTest() {
        
    String homepageTitle = homepage.validateHomePage();
    System.out.println("Print HomePage Title:::::::::::::::::" +homepageTitle);
    Assert.assertEquals(homepageTitle, "Cogmento CRM","Homepage title is not matching");
        
    }
    
    @Test 
    public void verifyUsernameTest() {
        Assert.assertTrue(homepage.verifyUsername(), "Username is not matching");
        
    }
    
    @Test
    public void verifyUserTest() {
        String Username = homepage.validateUser();
        Assert.assertEquals(Username, "Gokul Kuppusamy","Username text is not matching");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void verifyContactPageTest() {
        System.out.println("Clicking Contact Page");

        contactpage = homepage.clickContactLink();
                
    }
    
    @AfterMethod
    
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}

package com.crm.qa.TestCases;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.qa.base.TestBase;
import com.qa.pages.ContactPage;
import com.qa.pages.HomePage;
import com.qa.pages.loginPage;

public class ContactPageTest extends TestBase {

    loginPage loginpage;
    HomePage homepage;
    ContactPage contactpage;

    public ContactPageTest() {

        super();
    }

    @BeforeMethod

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        initializtion();
        loginpage = new loginPage();
        // Login method is returning homepage object
        homepage = loginpage.login(prop.getProperty("username"), prop.getProperty("password"));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        homepage.validateHomePageDisplayed();
        /*
         * Thread.sleep(3000); homepage.clickContactLink(null);
         */

    }

    @Test
    public void verifyContactsPageNewButtonTest() {
    
        Assert.assertTrue(contactpage.verifyNewButton());
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void verifyContactsPageLableTest() {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Assert.assertTrue(contactpage.verifyContactlable(), "Contacts is missing on the page");

    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void selectContactDetailsTest() {
        contactpage.selectContactDetails();
    }

    @AfterMethod

    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.crm.qa.TestCases.ContactPageTest.verifyContactsPageNewButtonTest(ContactPageTest.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: verifyContactsPageNewButtonTest method has an assert with a nullptr exception with ContactPage contactpage. Just wrap it in a try catch. Try to initialize it somewhere.

Comment: What about `contactpage=new ContsctPage()` as @arundeep chohan mentioned?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
initializtion();
        loginpage = new loginPage();

//below line is missing please add in HomePageTest class 
       **homepage=new Homepage();**
```

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm whether you are using only one driver instance for all pages, Basically Null point exception occurring for this , The solution uses a global variable for driver instance

**public static Webdrivr driver;**

Comment: Yes, I am using one driver instance for all the pages in TestBase.class as "public static Webdriver driver;"

Comment: did you create objects for all pages?
without creating objects for all pages you can get null point. exception
it seems you are not assign homepage obj check your contractPageTest(but you are. creating)


example
_______

Homepage homepage=new Homepage();